# Core Data text into URL for RSS iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, core-data, rss

I have this code to configure a cell for Core Data:
Code:

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"data"] description];
}
```

But what i want to do is when i click the row, here:
Code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Navigation logic may go here -- for example, create and push another view controller.
     RssFunViewController *rssFun = [[RssFunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RssFunViewController" bundle:nil];
     //NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:rssFun animated:YES];
     [rssFun release];

}
```

Insert the row text into the URL here:
Code:

```
-(BOOL)fetchAndParseRss{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

   //To suppress the leak in NSXMLParser
   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=lindsay+lohan&fr=news-us-ss"];
   BOOL success = NO;
   NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
   [parser setDelegate:self];
   [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:YES];
   [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:YES];
   [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
   success = [parser parse];
   [parser release];
   [pool drain];
   return success;
}
```

So where it says lindsay+lohan, i will put the users search term in here. The thing is, the 3rd piece of code is in BlogRss.m and the first two bits and in RootViewController.m?? Not sure how to make the link?? Any ideas...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `NSManagedObject` into the incoming view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
{
  // Navigation logic may go here -- for example, create and push another view controller.
  RssFunViewController *rssFun = [[RssFunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RssFunViewController" bundle:nil];
  NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  [rssFun setSelectedObject:selectedObject];
  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:rssFun animated:YES];
  [rssFun release], rssFun = nil;
}
```

This means that your `RssFunViewController` needs to have a property called `selectedObject` which is declared as a `NSManagedObject`.

Then you can finish your method:

```
- (BOOL)fetchAndParseRss 
{
   NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

   [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

   //To suppress the leak in NSXMLParser
   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
   [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];

   NSString *terms = [[self selectedObject] vaueForKey:@"data"];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stirngWithFormat:@"http://news.search.yahoo.com/rss?ei=UTF-8&p=%@&fr=news-us-ss", terms]];
```

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks for this detailed answer, definitely useful, but the thing with my app is that the code with the URL in, resides in BlogRssParser.m which in turn fills RssFunViewController view. So i need to make a link between RootViewController and BlogRssParser? So BlogRssParser can fill RssFunViewController's tableview...that make sense?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The answer is still the same. You need to pass a reference to the managed object from the controller that knows about it to the controller (or object) that doesn't know about it.